# Centering Banner in Einstein Content Selection

Tags: einstein

Hello I have an email that I am using custom blocks with and I dropped in an einstein content selection block.  The issue is this block is left aligned and I am unable to make it centered.  On top of that it it looks really big.  Whenever I try to add custom html it overrides my code.

Is there a way to center the banner in my email?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Display Size setting for the block (under the Selection Spotlight)? You can set the height or width in pixels, or use the max-width setting.

*Update: A new feature has been added to help align the block.
[image]